# File shows empty while sending to server through reactjs form

Tags: php, reactjs

I have made a form in ReactJS having multiple types of input and file type is one of them. What I want to do is send an attachment to mail using PHP. But whenever I send data through form all data get accessed in PHP file except for file type. When I checked in network file shows empty? but in console the file object get print what did I miss?

**form**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
    import axios from 'axios';
    import validator from 'validator';
    import isEmail from 'validator/lib/isEmail';
    const initialState = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        check1: '',
        check2: '',
        check3: '',
        check4: '',
        check5: '',
        check6: '',
        phone: '',
        budget: '',
        file: '',
        message: '',
        mailSent: false,
        error: null,
        nameError: '',
        emailError: '',
        phoneError: '',
        budgetError: '',
        fileError: '',
        messageError: ''
    
    }
    const API_PATH = 'api/contact/get_a_quote.php';
    class get_a_quote extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = initialState;
            this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
        }
    
        validate = () => {
            let nameError = "";
            let emailError = "";
            let phoneError = "";
            let budgetError = "";
            let fileError = "";
            let messageError = "";
    
            if (this.state.name.length <= 0) {
                nameError = "Name cannot be blank";
            }
            if (this.state.email.length <= 0) {
                emailError = "Email address cannot be blank";
            } else if (!this.state.email.includes('@')) {
                emailError = "Enter valid email address";
            }
            if (this.state.phone.length <= 0) {
                phoneError = "Phone Number cannot be blank";
            } else if (!validator.isMobilePhone(this.state.phone)) {
                phoneError = "Enter valid Phone Number";
            }
            if (this.state.budget.length <= 0) {
                budgetError = "Name cannot be blank";
            } else if (!validator.isNumeric(this.state.budget)) {
                budgetError = "Name cannot be blank";
            }
            if (this.state.message.length <= 0) {
                messageError = "Name cannot be blank";
            }
    
    
            if (nameError || emailError || phoneError || budgetError ||| messageError) {
                this.setState({ nameError, phoneError, emailError, budgetError, messageError });
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
                return false
            }
    
            return true;
        };
    
        handleInputChange = (event) => {
            const target = event.target;
            const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.value : target.checked;
            const name = target.name;
        
            this.setState({
              [name]: value
            });
          }
    
        handleFormSubmit = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            const isValid = this.validate();
            if (isValid) {
                console.log(this.state.file, this.state.phone, this.state.budget, this.state.mailSent, this.state.error);
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
                this.setState(initialState);
            }
    var formData = new FormData();
    
            formData.append(
             "image",
             this.state.file,
             this.state.file.name,
           );
          console.warn(this.state.file);
            console.warn(this.state.file.name);
           axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: `${API_PATH}`,
                headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
                 data: {'name':this.state.name,
          'email': this.state.email,
        'phone':this.state.phone,
      'message': this.state.message,
      'budget': this.state.budget,
      'check1': this.state.check1,
      'check2': this.state.check2,
      'check3': this.state.check3,
      'check4': this.state.check4,
      'check5': this.state.check5,
      'check6': this.state.check6,
      'file': formData,
    'error':this.state.error}
            })
                .then(result => {
                    this.setState({
                        mailSent: result.data.sent
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }));
     };
        render() {
            const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
            return (
                <div>
    <section className="checkout-area ptb-100">
                        <div className="container">
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                        <div className="billing-details">
                                            <h3 className="title font-weight-bold">Get A Quote</h3>
                                            <div className="row">
    <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12 pb-5 mt-1">
                                                    <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-6 my-1">
                                                        <label className="font-weight-bold">Services<span className="required" style={{ color: "#f16527" }}>*</span></label>
                                                        <div className="row">
                                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
     <div className="form-check">
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="create-an-account" name="check1" 
                                                                    value="Enterprise
                                                                    Software Solutions"
                                                                     onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                                                     checked={this.state.check1}
                                                                    />
                                                                    <label className="form-check-label" for="Enterprise Software Solutions">Enterprise
         Software Solutions</label>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                                <div className="form-check">
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="ship-different-address" name="check2"
                                                                        value="Web Development "
                                                                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                                                        checked={this.state.Web_Development}/>
                                                                    <label className="form-check-label" for="Web Development">Web Development </label>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                                <div className="form-check">
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="ship-different-address" name="check3" 
                                                                        value="Mobile App Development"
                                                                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                                                        checked={this.state.check3}/>
                                                                    <label className="form-check-label" for="Mobile App Development ">Mobile App Development
         </label>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                                <div className="form-check">
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="ship-different-address" name="check4" 
                                                                       value="UI & UX Design"
                                                                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                                                        checked={this.state.check4}
                                                                    />
                                                                    <label className="form-check-label" for="UI & UX Design">UI & UX Design</label>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                                <div className="form-check">
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="ship-different-address" name="check5"
                                                                        value="Digital Marketing"
                                                                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                                                        checked={this.state.check5} />
                                                                    <label className="form-check-label" for="Digital Marketing">Digital Marketing</label>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            
                                                            <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                                <div className="form-check">
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="ship-different-address" name="check6"
                                                                        value="Others"
                                                                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                                                        checked={this.state.check6} />
                                                                    <label className="form-check-label" for="Digital Marketing">Others</label>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                           
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            {/* <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                                <div className="form-check">
                                                                    <input type="checkbox" class
                                                                    Name="form-check-input" id="ship-different-address" name="check6" 
                                                                        value="Others"
                                                                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
      checked={this.state.check6} />
                                                                    <label className="form-check-label" for="Others">Others</label>
                                                                </div>
    
                                                            </div>
                                                        */}
                                                       
                                                        </div>
    
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-6 my-1">
                                                        <div className="form-group mt-5">
                                                                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="name"  placeholder="Name*"
                                                                value={this.state.name}
                                                                onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })} />
                                                            {this.state.nameError ? (<div className="text-danger">{this.state.nameError}</div>) : null}
                                                        </div>
    
                                                    </div>
    
                                                    <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-6 my-1">
                                                        <div className="form-group">
                                                            
                                                            <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email"  placeholder="Email*"
                                                                value={this.state.email}
                                                                onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })} />
                                                            {this.state.emailError ? (<div className="text-danger">{this.state.emailError}</div>) : null}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
     <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-6 my-1">
                                                        <div className="form-group">
                                                          
                                                            <input type="tel" className="form-control" name="phone"  placeholder="Mobile Number*"
                                                                value={this.state.phone}
                                                                onChange={e => this.setState({ phone: e.target.value })}
                                                            />
                                                            {this.state.phoneError ? (<div className="text-danger">{this.state.phoneError}</div>) : null}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-6 my-1">
                                                        <div className="form-group mt-5">
                                                            
                                                            <input type="number" className="form-control" name="budget"  placeholder="Budget*"
                                                                value={this.state.budget}
                                                                onChange={e => this.setState({ budget: e.target.value })} />
                                                            {this.state.budgetError ? (<div className="text-danger">{this.state.budgetError}</div>) : null}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
    
    
                                                    <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 my-1">
                                                        <div className="form-group">
                                                          
                                                            <input type="file" className="form-control pt-3" name="file" id="file"
                                                                // value={this.state.file}
                                                                onChange={e => this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] })} />
                                                            {this.state.fileError ? (<div className="text-danger">{this.state.fileError}</div>) : null}
    
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 my-1">
                                                        <div className="form-group">
                                                            
                                                            <textarea name="message" id="message" className="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" data-error="Please enter your message" placeholder="Write your message..." value={this.state.message}
onChange={e => this.setState({ message: e.target.value })}></textarea>
{this.state.messageError ? (<div className="text-danger">{this.state.messageError}</div>) : null}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
{isLoggedIn ? (<div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                                        <input type="submit" className="default-btn" Value="Send Message" onClick={e => this.handleFormSubmit(e)} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" />
    </div>) : <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                                            <input type="submit" className="default-btn" Value="Send Message" onClick={e => this.handleFormSubmit(e)} />
    </div>}
    </div>
    <div className="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pl-5">
                                                    <div className="main-banner-image wow fadeInUp"
                                                        data-wow-delay="00ms"
                                                        data-wow-duration="1000ms"
                                                        data-speed="0.06"
                                                        data-revert="true" width="690px" height="50%">
                                                        <img src="assets/img/contact.png" alt="our services" /> </div>
     </div>
    </div>
                                        </div>
    </div>
  
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </section >
```

> get_a_quote.php

```
<?php
require 'smtp/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);
if ($_POST)
    {
        $services = array($_POST['check1'], $_POST['check2'], $_POST['check3'], $_POST['check4'], $_POST['check5'], $_POST['check6']);
        $services = implode("\n\r,", $services);
        $m = new PHPMailer(true);
$m->isSMTP();
        $m->SMTPAuth = true;
        $m->SMTPdebug = 2;
        $m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $m->Username = '************';
        $m->Password = '************';
        $m->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $m->Port = 587;
        $m->addAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file']['name']);
        $m->isHTML(true);
        $m->setFrom($_POST['email'],'Grawlix');
        $m->addReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
        $m->Subject = 'New estimation request';
        $m->Body = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
            <style>
            /* Reset styles */ 
            body {
              font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;
              height: 100% !important;
              margin: 0; 
              min-width: 100%;
              padding: 0; 
              width: 100% !important; 
            }
            body, table, td, div, p, a {
              line-height: 100%;
              text-size-adjust: 100%;
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
              -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
              -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            }
            table, td {
              border-collapse: collapse !important; 
              border-spacing: 0;
              mso-table-lspace: 0pt; 
              mso-table-rspace: 0pt; 
            }
            img {
              border: 0; 
              line-height: 100%; 
              outline: none; 
              text-decoration: none; 
              -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
            }
            .action-item {
              border: 1px solid #005f7f;
              color: #005f7f;
              padding: 8px 20px;
            }
            .action-item:hover {
              background-color: #005f7f;
              border: 1px solid #005f7f;
              color: #fff;
            }
            #outlook a {padding: 0;}
            .ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}
            .ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
            .ExternalClass, 
            .ExternalClass p, 
            .ExternalClass span, 
            .ExternalClass font, 
            .ExternalClass td, 
            .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
        
            /* Rounded corners for advanced mail clients only */ 
            @media all and (min-width: 560px) {
              .container {
                border-radius: 8px; 
                -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
                -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
                -khtml-border-radius: 8px;
              }
            }
            /* Set color for auto links (addresses, dates, etc.) */ 
            a, a:hover {color: #005f7f;}
            .footer a, 
            .footer a:hover {
              color: #999999;
            }
             </style>
            <!-- MESSAGE SUBJECT -->
            <title>New Onboarding Request</title>
        </head>
        <body topmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; line-height: 100%; background-color: #ececec; color: #333333;" bgcolor="#ececec" text="#333333">
        <!-- WRAPPER TABLE -->
        <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%;">
          <tr>
            <br>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#ececec">
              <!-- WRAPPER -->
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="560" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; width: inherit; width: 560px; margin: 30px 0 0 0;" class="container">
              
                
                <!-- PRIMARY IMAGE -->
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-top: 20px;">
                    <img border="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" src="https://pms.grawlixsoft.com/files/system/_file60538f7abc879-site-logo.png" alt="Builders Mutual" title="Builders Mutual" width="560" style="border: none; color: #333333; display: block; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; max-width: 560px; padding: 0; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: 100%; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- CONTENT -->
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; padding-left: 6.25%; padding-right: 6.25%; width: 87.5%;">
                    <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 160%; color: #333333; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif; margin: 30px 0 0 0;">To Admin,</p>
                
                    <h3 style="color: #333; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 800; line-height: 120%; margin: 20px 0 10px 0; padding: 0; text-align: left;">Request Summary</h3>
                    <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 160%; color: #333333; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="font-weight: 800;">Requestor</span>: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 160%; color: #333333; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="font-weight: 800;">Phone</span>: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 160%; color: #333333; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="font-weight: 800;">Email </span>: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 160%; color: #333333; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="font-weight: 800;">Request Date</span>: '.date("d/m/Y").' </p>
                    <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 160%; color: #333333; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="font-weight: 800;">Services</span>: '.$services.'</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 160%; color: #333333; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="font-weight: 800;">Budget</span>: '.$_POST['budget'].'</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 160%; color: #333333; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="font-weight: 800;">Message</span>: '.$_POST['message'].'</p></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- LINE BREAK -->
                <tr>    
                  <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 6.25%; padding-right: 6.25%; padding-top: 10px; width: 87.5%;" class="line"><hr color="#e0e0e0" align="center" width="100%" size="1" noshade style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                 </table>
              <!-- FOOTER -->
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="560" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; width: inherit; max-width: 560px;" class="wrapper">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; color: #999999; font-family: "Roboto", Arial, sans-serif;" class="footer">
                      Copyright © 2021 Grawlix. All Rights Reserved.
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>';
            $m->AddAddress("*************", "*****");
        $m->SMTPOptions = array('ssl'=>array(
            'verify_peer'=>false,
            'verify_peer_name'=>false,
            'allow_self_signed'=>false,
        ));
    if ($m->send()) {
            echo json_encode(array(
                "sent" => true
            ));
            echo 'mail sent successfully';
        } else {
            echo json_encode(["sent" => false, "message" => "Something went wrong"]);
            echo "something went wrong" . $m->ErrorInfo;
        }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
You must use FileReader() to generate base64 image and
use URL.createObjectURL() to generate preview image

Example :

```js
function handleImageChange(e){
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  const initFile = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
  reader.onloadend = () => {
      //send to another function
      this.uploadImage(reader.result, initFile); 
  };
}

function uploadImage = (file, path) => {
    this.setState({
        img_profile_preview: path,
        img_profile: file
    });
};
```